# Why does this not skip a line between each element in the list?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, stringify

I have a list of times called inf_inf that looks like this

```
inf_inf = [[100, 300], [400, 500], [700, 900]]
```

I'm trying to transfer that list to a html page, but the problem is I need each time pair ([100, 300]) to be an its own line.

```
document.getElementById("inf_times").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(inf_inf.join("\n"))
```

I thought this would do it but it's not working.  I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: Line breaks don't have meaning in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

with innerHTML, you could join with

```
 ('<br/>');
```

and does not need JSON.Stringify. Example :

```
 document.getElementById("inf_times").innerHTML = inf_inf.join("<br/>")
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  So simple I never would have thought of that.  I was diving deep into different stringify possibilities.  You don't happen to have a good tutorial/information on JSON.stringify do you?  Besides the usual stuff google brings up.

Comment: @RabidGorilla I've edit a little bit, hope it works :). 
Edit : JSON.stringify is using to parse a JSON object into string, for storage, display, etc... in this case you don't need it.

Comment: @RabidGorilla: What is it that you don't understand about `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: *"JSON.stringify is using to parse a JSON object [...]"*: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You mean "JavaScript object".

Comment: I was just playing around with the, "replacer" and "space" options with it.  I couldn't figure out how to get it to do what I needed in this case so I was looking for a page with a lot of different examples with it in use.  I was using this as a ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify  which was helpful.  Thanks again people, I'm sure I'll need more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
var inf_inf = [[100, 300], [400, 500], [700, 900]];
document.getElementById("inf_times").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(inf_inf.join("<br/>"));
```

Comment: [*join*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5) returns a string, there is no need to stringify a string.